# VBA WebScraping returning nothing to excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I've been trying to scrape data from a WebSite, as my previous question indicates.
I was able to figure what my problem was thanks to the comunity, but now I'm facing another problem.
I don't get any error this time, but the program doesn't export any values to excel, my page still all blank.

**On the other website I was scraping from, the `HTML.Elements` were `divs` and now it's `spans`, it's because of that?**

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Loiça()
    Dim data As Object, i As Long, html As HTMLDocument, r As Long, c As Long, item As Object, div As Object
    Set html = New HTMLDocument                  '<== VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim numPages As Long
    numPages = GetNumberOfPages

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
       ' numResults = arr(UBound(arr))
       ' numPages = 1

        For i = 1 To numPages
             If i > 1 Then
                .Open "GET", Replace$("https://mediamarkt.pt/pages/search-results-page?q=maquina+roupa&page=1", "page=1", "page=" & i), False
                .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
                .send
                 html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            End If
            Set data = html.getElementsByClassName("snize-title")
            For Each item In data
                r = r + 1: c = 1
                For Each div In item.getElementsByTagName("span")
                    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Loiça")
                        .Cells(r, c) = div.innerText
                    End With
                    c = c + 1
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End With
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
End Sub
Public Function GetNumberOfPages() As Long
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate2 "https://mediamarkt.pt/pages/search-results-page?q=maquina+roupa&page=1"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim numPages As Long, numResults As Long, arr() As String
        arr = Split(.document.querySelector(".snize-search-results-header").innerText, Chr$(32))
        numResults = arr(LBound(arr))
        GetNumberOfPages = numResults
        .Quit
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: If you take a look at the page source the class `snize-title` isn't present when it is loaded which is why you aren't getting any results

Comment: You cant solve this issue by using `With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")`.  The site you are trying to access uses javascript and you have to build a solution that uses   ONLY `Dim IE As New InternetExplorer`. You should learn how to automate IE from VBA in the case of this particular page.

Comment: @Mig yes it is present after it is loaded, but the way you're scraping the page won't load the js so it is not present for your scraper

Comment: Here you go - the data is actually loaded via a call to the url: [json link](https://www.searchanise.com/getresults?api_key=5G0b7c8K0r&q=maquina+roupa&sortBy=relevance&sortOrder=desc&startIndex=0&maxResults=50&items=true&pages=true&categories=true&suggestions=true&queryCorrection=true&suggestionsMaxResults=3&pageStartIndex=0&pagesMaxResults=20&categoryStartIndex=0&categoriesMaxResults=20&facets=true&facetsShowUnavailableOptions=false&ResultsTitleStrings=2&ResultsDescriptionStrings=2&output=jsonp&callback=jQuery22405933330900677585_1551880363920&_=1551880363921)

Comment: You may be able to get away with just scraping the json url instead

Comment: @Yane When I tried to replace that for IE it loads toons of IE pages (based on the numResults variable) and it takes tooooo long, yet stil shows blank values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The info is loaded dynamically. You need to use IE throughout. Also, change your css selector

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriterResults()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, i As Long, data As Object, span As Object, item As Object, r As Long, c As Long
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://mediamarkt.pt/pages/search-results-page?q=maquina+roupa&page=1"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim numPages As Long, numResults As Long, arr() As String
        arr = Split(.document.querySelector(".snize-search-results-header").innerText, Chr$(32))
        numResults = arr(LBound(arr))
        Dim resultsPerPage As Long
        resultsPerPage = .document.querySelectorAll(".snize-overhidden").Length
        numPages = Application.RoundUp(numResults / resultsPerPage, 0)
        For i = 1 To numPages
            If i > 1 Then
                .Navigate2 Replace$("https://mediamarkt.pt/pages/search-results-page?q=maquina+roupa&page=1", "page=1", "page=" & i)
                While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            End If
            Set data = .document.getElementsByClassName("snize-overhidden")
            For Each item In data
                r = r + 1: c = 1
                For Each span In item.getElementsByTagName("span")
                    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Loiça")
                        .Cells(r, c) = span.innerText
                    End With
                    c = c + 1
                Next
            Next
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh... so I always need to use the same method depending on the page? If i start with IE I have to do the whole project with IE as well then? Thanks a lot btw !!

Comment: Seems like that may be the case unless an API is available