# VBA WebScraping return empty values

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I have the following code to scrape data from a website, the problem is that it isn't scraping any data, it doesn't show any errors but doesn't give me any results as well...

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Loiça()
Sheets("Loiça").Range("A:A,Z:Z").EntireColumn.Delete
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, i As Long, data As Object, div As Object, item As Object, r As Long, c As Long
    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate2 "https://www.radiopopular.pt/categoria/maquina-de-lavar-louca/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim numResults As Long, arr() As String
        arr = Split(.document.querySelector(".status.cb").innerText, Chr$(32))
        numResults = arr(LBound(arr))
        Dim resultsPerPage As Long
        resultsPerPage = .document.querySelectorAll(".data cb").Length
            If i > 1 Then
                .Navigate2 ("https://www.radiopopular.pt/categoria/maquina-de-lavar-louca/")
                While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            End If
            Set data = .document.getElementsByClassName("data cb")
            For Each item In data
                r = r + 1: c = 1
                For Each div In item.getElementsByTagName("div")
                    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Loiça")
                        .Cells(r, c) = div.innerText
                    End With
                    c = c + 1
                Next
            Next
        .Quit
    End With
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------'
End Sub
```

Comment: The loop never triggers, i dont believe you can do a `.document.getElementByClassName("data db").getElementByTagName("div")` which is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA WebScraping returning nothing to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55024184/vba-webscraping-returning-nothing-to-excel)

Comment: @Tom no it isn't I've already taked a look at it and it still wont work.

Comment: @RicardoA so what's would be the best solution here?

Comment: You have to somehow differentiate the <div> tags you want with other you dont want and loop them by skipping the "data cb". `for each div in .document.getElementsByTagName("div")` meaning you have to loop all <div> tags on the whole document/webpage.

Comment: I think I may have found out the problem or an additional problem. This website wont load any results on Internet Explorer. Set .Visible to True and remove/comment the .Quit so you can see the website when the Subscript runs.

Comment: It's the same issue that you had with your other webpage. The data is loaded dynamically and as such isn't there when you scrape the page. Which is why your `NumResults` equals 0 and your `data` variable is empty. You've also left in a load of variables (e.g. `i`) which are never set so your `If` block will never be entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a fun challenge. Some points to note:

1. The page doesn't seem to load in Internet Explorer (for me at least) - this may be because legacy browsers not supported. Therefore, switching to [Selenium basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/issues) and Chrome was needed. After downloading selenium basic and installing, you may have to swop the `ChromeDriver.exe` in the selenium folder for the [latest](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). You then need to go VBE > Tools > References > Add a reference to `Selenium Type Library`.
2. The page loads dynamically with ajax in batches of 12 records. You need to scroll the page until all results present.
3. You cannot retrieve the results count in the same way as you show as the string returned is a different, and possibly variable format. Instead you can grab the total from an element which stores this number.
4. To continue with the syntax for writing out you have, you need to transfer the page html into an HTMLDocument variable and then work with that.

---

VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Loiça()
    Dim d As WebDriver, t As Date, i As Long, data As Object, div As Object, item As Object, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim numResults As Long, html As HTMLDocument
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 600
    Const URL As String = "https://www.radiopopular.pt/categoria/maquina-de-lavar-louca/"

    Set d = New ChromeDriver

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL

        Worksheets("Loiça").Range("A:A,Z:Z").EntireColumn.Delete
        numResults = .FindElementByCss("#total").Text
        t = Timer
        Do
            .ExecuteScript "window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);", "javascript"
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop Until .FindElementByCss("#products").Text = numResults
        Set html = New HTMLDocument
        html.body.innerHTML = .PageSource
        Set data = html.getElementsByClassName("data")
        For Each item In data
            r = r + 1: c = 1
            For Each div In item.getElementsByTagName("div")
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Loiça")
                    .Cells(r, c) = div.innerText
                End With
                c = c + 1
            Next
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```